# Why is $\int 1/6 \cdot y^3 e^{-y} dy = \int 1/2\cdot y^2 e^{-y} dy$

Tags: integration

I am currently learning for a stochastics exam. In a solution to an exam from 2012 I found one step:

$$\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{6} \cdot y^3 e^{-y} \mathrm{d}y = \int_0^\infty \frac{1}{2} \cdot y^2 e^{-y} \mathrm{d}y$$

Why is that the case? Given the left side of the equation, how does one solve such integrals?

Comment: Hint: IBP. $ $ $ $

Comment: use integration by parts. remeber to use $\lim_{y \to \infty} \frac{y^k}{e^y} = 0$ for any $k.$

Comment: This is the [$\Gamma$ function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function).

Comment: @Did: Is IBP an abbreviation? Could you please spell it out? (English is not my mother tongue and it's hard to search for abbreviations)

Comment: `integration by parts`.

Answer (score 1):

the problem at hand can be solved by integrating by parts formula $\int u\,dv = uv - \int v\,du$.

$$\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{6} y^3 e^{-y} \,dy = \int_0^\infty \frac{1}{6} y^3   d(-e^{-y}) = \frac{1}{6} y^3(-e^{-y})|_0^\infty+\frac{1}{2} \int_0^\infty y^2e^{-y} \, dy = \frac{1}{2} \int_0^\infty y^2e^{-y} \, dy  $$

---

once you know the form of  $$\int e^{-x}x^3 \, dx = (ax^3 + bx^2 + cx + d)e^{-x}$$ it is easier to find the coefficients by differentiating the above equation and equating the coefficients of the powers of $x$.

on differentiating we get $$e^{-x}x^3 = -(ax^3 + bx^2 + cx + d)e^{-x}+(3ax^2 + 2bx + c)e^{-x} $$  divide it out by $e^{-x}$ and equate the coefficients gives you $$ a = -1, b = 3a = -3, c = 2b = -6, d = c = -6$$

Answer (score 0):

Product rule for Integration with $u(y) = e^{-y},v(y)=\frac{y^3}{6}$:

$\int_0^\infty  u'(y)v(y)dy = - \int_0^\infty  u(y)v'(y)dy + u(y)v(y)|_0^\infty $